Issue with PUT method not finding the product to update
So I want to update products using REST API PUT method in my woocommerce and it doesn't work even if the keys are correct. That said, when I use the GET method(I used Postman to test), it can find the product using the same URL. Here's the code that I'm using.
function update_product_price($product_id, $price, $woocommerce_url, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret) {
    // WooCommerce API credentials
    $woocommerce_url = 'domain.net/wp-json/wc/v3/products/';
    $consumer_key = 'ck-key';
    $consumer_secret = 'cs-key';

    // Data to update product price
    $data = array(
        'regular_price' => $price
    );
    // Initialize cURL session
    $ch = curl_init();
    error_log($woocommerce_url);
    // Set cURL options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $woocommerce_url . $product_id);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($consumer_key . ':' . $consumer_secret)
    ));

    // Execute cURL request
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // Close cURL session
    curl_close($ch);
    // Check response status
    if ($http_status == 200) {
        return true; // Product updated successfully
    } else {
        return $response; // Error message
    }
}

I tried to use PATCH and POST and it did not work. Tried making the url to "domain.net/wp-json/wc/v3/products?sku=" still 404 error.

This is fixed now - the issues was in my variable being sent in the function.
